# Multiple databases with node and typeorm

Tags: node.js, typeorm

Is it possible to create a backend in node with typeorm that has a login system, and depending on the user logged in it connects to a different database? I would have to change the connection settings, while running the backend, it would be according to the login.

I researched about but only found how to do it with 2 fixed databases, with the connections already configured in the ormconfig.

Username, password, host would always be the same. What would change would be the name of the database. For example, if I logged in with user "test",  I have to connect to the database named "test", if I logged in with user "stackoverflow" I have to connect to the database "stackoverflow".

The solution I thought: when sending a GET for example, send with the authentication token, and the token would have the name of the database that I must connect to. From that information I have to connect to a different database. If I create a authentication middleware and call a new createConnection inside, passing the name that came in the request, would it work? It is possible?

Another possible problem: the "standard" database would have a different structure than other databases (when users are logged in). How would the backend models work? I'm very confused.

Any possible idea of ​​how to do this will be very welcome, thanks!

Edit:

I tried to call a new createConnection passing another database name, got this error:

```
(node:14033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.
at new AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/src/error/AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError.ts:8:9)
at ConnectionManager.create (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:57:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/src/index.ts:232:35)
at step (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
at Object.next (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
at /Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:75
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.__awaiter (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:111:16)
at Object.createConnection (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/node_modules/typeorm/index.js:192:20)
at Object.Conecta (/Users/osdinformatica/Desktop/node/src/database/index.ts:4:3)
(node:14033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14033) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: It's possible to connect to as many different databases as your underlying resources will allow. However I would advise against this type of design unless it is absolutely, 100% necessary, as it becomes significantly more cumbersome to maintain once fragmented in this way.

Comment: it's 100% necessary :( , can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that i found is to use EntityManager and run raw queries.

```
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';
...
const entityManager = getManager();
const test = await entityManager.query('select * from db.table where id = 0;');
```